# Can I separate a constant within an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question**

I was wondering if it was possible to remove a constant out of an integral?

example integral: $\int_1^7(f(x)+5)=\int_1^7(f(x))+\int_1^7(5)$

So my question is whether the above statement is possible?

Comment: You can always split an integral along a $+$ or $-$ however you like (but unfortunately not for multiplication; also, be careful with the minus distributing in your new integral). For example $\int x^2+3x+5 dx = \int x^2 dx + \int 3x+5 dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is valid and is [the sum rule for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_integration). This is due to the [linearity of the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration). Rather than thinking in terms of proving this as true analytically, think about this graphically. Given $f(x)=x^2$, $\;f(x)+5=x^2+5$:

[image]

If we want to find:

$$\int_0^2 f(x)+5 \,\mathrm dx$$

By the sum rule, we can split it up:

$$\int_0^2 f(x) \,\mathrm dx + \int_0^2 5 \,\mathrm dx$$

And each integral represents a separate area:

[image]

Once we split the integral up, the first integral gives us the blue part, while the latter one the green part. This makes sense because adding a constant $5$ shifts the graph up $5$ units. Once we integrate, the whole area under the graph will be the original area under the graph, *plus a new rectangle of height $5$*, because the area under a constant function is a rectangle.

This then can be extended for arbitrary integrands because the area under a curve can be split up in the same way as above into two integrals, one for each integrand.